# Hugging face model not transcribing the entire length of the audio file

Tags: nlp, artificial-intelligence, google-colaboratory, huggingface-transformers, openai-whisper

**Brief: I'm unable to transcribe more than a few seconds of audio in a 5 minute audio file using hugging face open ai whisper(finetuned) model.**
I'm facing issues with transcribing a Indian local language audio file using this(https://huggingface.co/thennal/whisper-medium-ml) hugging face model. It is only transcribing the first few seconds but I would like to get the entire file transcribed. I'm trying this on google collab.

### What I have tried?

First of all the code which only shows the first few seconds

```
print(pipe("/content/audio.mp3"))
```

Other code that I tried are using model **max_new_tokens** which resulted in even shorter transcription and I wasn't able to go above 500.
I tried **DEFAULT_INPUT_AUDIO_MAX_DURATION = 300** which resulted in an error.
I tried **asking bing** about this but it was just blurting things.

### What I want?

I would be grateful if someone could write the **code for me, which transcribes the entire audio file no matter what length it is.**

Answer (score 0):

In case that you have a very long audio file, we can chunking the initial audio file into shorter samples (e.g. 10 seconds for each chunk) before we let the model transcribe it. According to that, instead of transcribing the entire audio file at once, we will keep inference on each chunk in order to make it can handle with longer audio files. This can be done by passing one more parameters named `chunk_length_s`.

Moreover, your manually splitting into many chunks may result in a very slow inference since there has to handle many samples (manually typing is faster). This can be `accelerated by leverage the use of processing unit that is GPU (cuda)` by changing the runtime of your google colab from CPU to GPU first (can be T4 GPU) by following this [enabling GPU in Google Colab](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/google_colab/google_colab_using_free_gpu.htm). Then we will make an inference by utilizing GPU instead of CPU by default. it will result in much faster inference. here is a code to do it:

```py
# import high-level pipeline 
from transformers import pipeline
    
# This line will load your desired model + GPU activated
pipe = pipeline("automatic-speech-recognition", model="thennal/whisper-medium-ml", device="cuda")

# this will handle the longer audio file with faster inference utilizing GPU
print(pipe("path_to_audiofile.mp3", max_new_tokens=100, chunk_length_s=10)).
```

The explanation of how chunking works in automatic speech recognition can be read at [Making automatic speech recognition work on large files with Wav2Vec2 in  Transformers](https://huggingface.co/blog/asr-chunking). I recommend you to read this since it has another extra parameter that is `stride_length_s` that can be used to handle this case as well.

However, it seems like a `5 minutes` audio file is a very long. Handling that long audio files is more challenging. it is better to make your initial audio files to be shorter if you can before passing it as an input to the model.

Comment: Hi @xty, once again thanks for replying(on all the posts) I tried chunking but the results that I got were not good, the transcription started from 15th second of audio then stopped at around 25 and then again started around 1 minute 5 sec and ended again. The string was also small.
I'm considering splitting manually before loading but then maybe manually typing is faster than that.
I would appreciate if you have any more valuable input for my problem. I'm also reading the article that you suggested

Comment: Actually, it make sense that the transcription may not be covered all 5 minutes since it is a very long. However, as I said, splitting can be used to handle it. By splitting, you have to make an experiment by yourself to find the most appropriate chunk size that is  your best fit (I think that you probably found it now).  Now, the next problem is that it is very slow (manually typing is faster), this can be accelerated by leverage the use of processing unit that is GPU (cuda).  This implementation require some simple setting, i will re-edit my answer above. Then, you can try with that.

Comment: @user22347502 already edited. you can try it.

Comment: It works really well, not what I had when I started out but it's good, thanks to you. apparently the magic code is having chunk length plus stride length WITHOUT max new token. It's fast also after running it with cuda, in fact so fast that I thought I should swap the model for a whisper larger one(https://huggingface.co/anuragshas/whisper-large-v2-ml), but apparently it was not that fast, but fast enough for the model we were discussing. Thank you very much for all your help.

Comment: You’re welcome! @user22347502 don’t forget to make an upvote, so that others can find our discussion which may help them too!

Comment: I already tried upvoting but sadly stack exchange doesn't allow me to upvote because I'm a new user. I tried once again when you asked. They say I need atleast 15 reputation for that. But I really appreciate you helping me.

Comment: That’s fine. I’m glad helping you figure this thing out. Have a good day!

Comment: It was pleasure working with you to solve this. Once again Thank you.